# How to call R function (which should not be exported) from Rcpp?

Tags: r, package, rcpp

I want to call an R function of my package from an Rcpp function. Both R and Rcpp functions are part of the package [rminizinc](https://github.com/acharaakshit/RMiniZinc).

Currently, I am using the approach shown below:

```
    void fun(){
        Environment rmzn_env("package:rminizinc");
        Function retModel = rmzn_env["getRModel"];
        retModel(some_object);
   }
```

But, this approach only works when I export the `getRModel()` function. Is there any way I could call `getRModel()` without exporting it as I want it to be a helper function which should not be exposed to the user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to get a bit meta here. It is possible to get an environment containing all the unexported functions in a package using the base R function `asNamespace`. This function itself can be used inside Rcpp. You then create a new `Environment` from the output of that function, from which you can harvest the unexported function.

As an example, let's get the unexported function `ggplot2:::as_lower_ascii` to do some work on a string we pass to an Rcpp function:

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
CharacterVector fun(CharacterVector input){
  Function asNamespace("asNamespace");
  Environment ggplot_env = asNamespace("ggplot2");
  Function to_lower_ascii = ggplot_env["to_lower_ascii"];
  return to_lower_ascii(input);
}
```

So if we source this, then back in R we can do:

```r
fun("HELLO WORLD")
#> [1] "hello world"
```